# Polynomial whose only values are squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, square-numbers

Given a polynomial $ P \in \Bbb Z [X] $ such that, $ P (x)$ is the square of an integer for all integers x, is $ P $ necessarily of the form $ P (x)= Q (x)^2$ with $ Q \in \Bbb Z [X]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306685/58401), which gives a proof, and references [this article](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/poly2.pdf), which deals with the multivariate case.